# What is the Standard Duration of Collaboration with a Professor for a First Research Paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, academic-life, collaboration, mentoring

What is the standard or typical length of time students work with a professor while both are at the same university, specifically for the purpose of writing their first paper together?

I understand that the nature of research and the field of study might influence the duration. I am actually looking for reasons why this collaboration won't continue maybe forever until retirement.

Comment: Can you maybe explain your concerns more directly? Wondering what the average duration is and then talking about it continuing until retirement seem like very different types of concerns... Are you talking about for an undergraduate student? Graduate student? And why wouldn't you ask the professor directly what they are expecting?

Comment: Will it continue forever?  In some cases, maybe.  But in most cases the student graduates, goes elsewhere, and works with others instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to Ph.D. students, rather than undergraduate students, as it is somewhat rare for undergraduate students to publish papers from undergraduate research projects.

There isn't really a standard or typical length. This is very field/research dependent, but is most dependent on the publishing rate of the professor, which is HIGHLY variable and influenced by a lot of different factors (including whether they're trying to get tenure, how soon they retire, how much funding they have, etc.) It is very common for Ph.D. programs to require that Ph.D. students publish X number of first author papers, so that requirement also influences frequency of publications.

As to when collaborations end - this is again very highly dependent on lots of factors. Most Ph.D. students will leave academia after graduation (this number is likely out of date, but as of about 8 years ago, only 8% of Ph.D.s became professors). If those students go on to work in industry, this can limit collaboration opportunities since industry is less focused on publishing than academia is. Some students don't like their Ph.D. supervisors, and thus choose not to work with them after graduation. Some students end up doing postdocs/work on topics that aren't of interest to their Ph.D. supervisor, and thus don't collaborate after graduation. Some students collaborate heavily with their Ph.D. supervisor for the rest of their careers.

Long story short - whether or not you want to collaborate with your supervisor after you graduate isn't dependent on them retiring, and entirely dependent upon whether both supervisor and student want to keep working together.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, collaborative relationships should, and can, continue past graduation and forever, so long as both (all) maintain common interests. This can be a very powerful boost to an early career academic, providing both support and ideas for new research projects.

The project may not continue forever, but the relationship can.

This assumes, of course, that everyone behaves correctly and (hmmm) collaboratively. Cross campus visits can bring new ideas into research groups, for example and can aid students of both (all) members.

It is common, however, though less than ideal, that such relationships end at the end of a project. It might, then, take work to reestablish them in the future.